# Taylor expansion of function with two vector inputs

Tags: taylor-expansion

How do I expand this [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsdUn.png) that takes in two vectors, r and x, using Taylor around =0 ? Is it (,)=(0,)+∇(0,)⋅(−0)+12(−0)⋅∇∇(0,)⋅(−0)+⋅⋅⋅ + The same thing for y
?

And how can I write it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwE9J.png) where C are the components of a tensor of rank l knowing r >> x?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations